# Transfer from session made in script to opening a selenium browser (and headless browser) on the same session

Tags: python, selenium, session, python-requests, headless-browser

So I have coded this script that sets a session then goes through a series of requests but at the end of the final request, I would like it to launch a (headless and) browser on the same session at the beginning then I will further automate processes.

Comment: could You please share the code?   I didnt get the question

Comment: The code is a bit private but, so the general gist of it is, at the beginning i have

Comment: s = requests.session()

Comment: then i def a couple functions, all the functions then run within this one session

Comment: All the functions are, request based and now I would like to transition the session from requests to browser

Comment: Please, edit your comments into a single comment, or put that information in the question itself. And in the meantime, try taking a look at [this page](https://www.guru99.com/handling-cookies-selenium-webdriver.html) about how to add cookies into selenium driven browser. I think that cookies are the most significant part of "transferring sessions"

Answer (score 0):

@Tony, apologies in advance if I misunderstood anything from the question - but basically task breaks down to transferring selenium session (cookies including sessionId if any) to selenium instance.

Recently I implemented similar solution in java bindings: had to extract cookies from selenium driver instance and had to put them  in rest-assured client instance for further API requests execution.

```
log.info("exctacting cookies from driver instance...... To use cookies for api requests");
Map<String, String> cookies = new HashMap<String, String>();

//        init cookies for resassured
Set<Cookie> driverCurrentCookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
for (Cookie c : driverCurrentCookies) {
    cookies.put(c.getName(), c.getValue());
}

log.info("cookies extracted: " + cookies.toString());
```

In  Your case- You need to do  inversion (idea at high level). Need to see Your code to provide more details